# Бот вк на vk_api

Tags: python-3.5

Написал простого бота, который если не находит ответ отвечает рандомными фразами.
А как сделать так, что бы бот мог меня название беседы, аватарку и откпреплять сообщение? Например когда страницу пригласили в беседу или что-то изменили в беседе

Comment: vk_api.messages.editChat(chat_id,название)

Comment: Спасибо, а как отследить событие например когда это название изменил кто-то другой или бота пригласили в беседу?

Comment: vk_api.messages.getChat(chat_ids)
а вообще вся эта информация есть в документации вк, https://vk.com/dev/methods

Comment: vk_session.method('messages.editChat', {'chat_id': event.chat_id, 'title': название}) получилось так. С сообщениями делаю проверку if event.from_user and not (event.from_me).
Но как-то не очень понятно как сделать проверку на что пользователь сменил название или добавил меня в беседу

Comment: Писал его через VkLongPoll

Comment: Через какое-то время получать название беседы и сравнивать с предыдущим.

Comment: Отслеживайте события longPoll (`VkEventType` или `VkBotEventType` Вам в помощь)

Comment: Ммм, ясно. Каждое событие проверять если название не равно нужному названию то менять его. А как поступить с фотографиями?

Comment: Нет, не каждое) Есть событие смены названия беседы, его и ждите. Событий много, все они описаны в документации.

Comment: А как получить название беседы?

Comment: if event.type == VkEventType.CHAT_UPDATE:
            if event.type_id == 1 and not (event.from_me):
                try:
                    vk_session.method('messages.editChat', {'chat_id': event.chat_id, 'title': cfname})
                except:
                    print('name error')
при обновлении беседы бот начинает изменять название до капчи. что не так?